# How to show all product subcategories on shop page (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm trying to show all the product subcategories after the title in woocommerce shop page.

I need to filter certains categories ID for hide them.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_all_categories_2', 80);
    function add_all_categories_2($parent_cat_NAME) {
        $id_producto = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'products');
        $args = array(
           'hierarchical' => 1,
           'show_option_none' => '',
           'hide_empty' => 1,
           'parent' => $parent_cat_NAME,
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',       
           'include' => array($id_producto)
         );
    $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
    foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
    echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
```

But I can't get only the categories from a product. It always are showing me all the categories.

**EDIT:** Now i'm testing whit this:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_all_categories', 80);
    function add_all_categories()
    {
    $cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    if ( ! empty( $cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) {

    // Loop through the product categories...

        foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
           echo '<span class="vee_category_title"><a href="'. get_term_link($term) .'"><span class="vee_category_title_'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</span></a> <span class="separador-cats">/</span> </span>';
        }

    }
    }
```

But whit this code i don't know hot to filter the categories.

I hope somebody can help a bit!

Thanks!!